Can we downgrade edition from SQL Server 2016 Enterprise to Standard when we have compression feature enabled?
I have a production database running on SQL Server 2016 Enterprise. I ran the below query to check the edition-specific feature and see the compression feature in use. Can we still downgrade the edition?
Query
SELECT feature_name
FROM sys.dm_db_persisted_sku_features;
GO 

Output
feature_name
Compression

Does this answer your question? why sys.dm_db_persisted_sku_features shows results that compatible with Standard edition?

From Microsoft Documentation



Feature
Enterprise
StandardwithAdvancedServices
Web
Express
Express




Columnstore 1, 2
Yes
Yes
Yes
Yes
Yes


In-Memory OLTP 1, 2
Yes
Yes
Yes
Yes 3
Yes


Stretch Database
Yes
Yes
Yes
Yes
Yes


Persistent Main Memory
Yes
Yes
Yes
Yes
Yes


Multi-instance support
50
50
50
50
50


Table and index partitioning 2
Yes
Yes
Yes
Yes
Yes


Data compression 2
Yes
Yes
Yes
Yes
Yes


Resource Governor
Yes
No
No
No
No


Partitioned Table Parallelism 2
Yes
Yes
Yes
No
No


Multiple Filestream containers 2
Yes
Yes
Yes
Yes
Yes


NUMA Aware Large Page Memory and Buffer Array Allocation
Yes
No 4
No
No
No


Buffer Pool Extension
Yes
Yes
No
No
No


I/O Resource Governance
Yes
No
No
No
No


Read-Ahead
Yes
No
No
No
No


Advanced Scanning
Yes
No
No
No
No


Delayed Durability
Yes
Yes
Yes
Yes
Yes



1 - In-Memory OLTP data size and Columnstore segment cache are limited to the amount of memory specified by edition in the Scale Limits section. The max degree of parallelism is limited. The degree of process parallelism (DOP) for an index build is limited to 2 DOP for the Standard Edition and 1 DOP for the Web and Express Editions. This refers to columnstore indexes created over disk-based tables and memory-optimized tables.
2 - Applies to SQL Server 2016 (13.x) SP1 as part of creating a Common Programmability Surface Area (CPSA) across editions. Aggregate Pushdown, String Predicate Pushdown, and SIMD Optimizations are SQL Server Enterprise Edition scalability enhancements. For more detail, see Columnstore indexes - what's new.
3 - This feature isn't included in the LocalDB installation option.
4 - Standard Edition and SQL Server + CAL-based licensing can restrict how many processors SQL Server Standard can use, but SQL Server Standard is NUMA aware.
As shown in the table above, you can downgrade to Standard Edition since the Data Compression feature is supported in all five editions of SQL Server 2016 (starting with Service Pack 1).
